# Coldfusion communication between servers

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

I need to receive data from one Coldfusion installation to another.
They are on different servers.

Right now I have web services created on remote server.
I use JSON format for receiving data, because of incredible overhead of using wsdl(I have a lot of text data to receive).

Is there any other viable way of communicating between 2 Coldfusion servers efficiently?

Leonty

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coldfusion-to-Coldfusion web service call: SOAP vs cfhttp method call vs cfhttp post?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273274/coldfusion-to-coldfusion-web-service-call-soap-vs-cfhttp-method-call-vs-cfhttp)

Comment: cfhttp to `cfc?method=` would be my choice.  I also added an `onCFCRequest()` to catch the exception and return a struct created from `CFCATCH` in Json.

Comment: If you are looking for optimum efficiency between two CF servers that you operate, and you have a relatively special-case need for data transfers, then it would be helpful if you provide more details about the specific types of data, and the specific circumstances of your need, so options that most suitably match your conditions can be offered.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using WDDX data packages.  ColdFusion has WDDX built-in through the CFWDDX tag.  You can convert any of CF's data structures to a WDDX package (essentially it will create an XML formatted string containing your information).  You can then transfer that string to another server through a variety of means including a form post, web service call, FTP file transfer, etc.  Once the receiving server has the data, use CFWDDX there to convert it back into a native data structure.